# How can I replace values in one Excel column with values concatenated from a variable number of columns in the same row?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to transform the output of an exported Excel report that contains many rows, each with a variable amount of columns that contain data.  The export can't be modified.  It's what I have to work with.

Column A may or may not contain text.  Column B contains data that isn't relevant to this problem (other than it's in the way and has to be coded around).  Columns C, D, and onward may or may not contain text but these text fills are consistent and sequential left to right, i.e., text will never "skip" a column — if Column E is the last column in the row containing text, Columns D and C will contain text too.

My goal is to concatenate all these separate text values into the Column A cell of each row (separated by the Vertical Line character), then be left with values only in Columns A and B.

So if the export looks like:

```
      ColA   ColB   ColC   ColD

Row1  Alpha  xxxxx
Row2
Row3  Gamma  xxxxx  Theta
Row4
Row5  Delta  xxxxx  Kappa  Sigma
```

The transformed output should look like:

```
      ColA                   ColB   ColC   ColD

Row1  Alpha                  xxxxx
Row2
Row3  Gamma | Theta          xxxxx  
Row4
Row5  Delta | Kappa | Sigma  xxxxx
```

(I know those aren't terrific representations, but I can't embed images.  Here's a ['Before' pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1m8j.jpg) and an ['After' pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyMyG.jpg) of the Excel sheets)

And now here's what I've coded so far.  It's only set up to concat Columns A and C.  I feel like I'm on the right track with regard to setting up ranges and getting the Vertical Line formatting correct between text strings, but I need to be able to handle variable column ranges per row — both for creating the concatenated text strings in Column A and deleting values in Column C onward once the routine is complete.

```
Sub ColumnConcat()

Dim firstComment As Range
Set firstComment = Range("A1")

Dim lastComment As Range
Set lastComment = Range("B1").End(xlDown).Offset(0, -1)

Dim commentRange As Range
Set commentRange = Range(firstComment, lastComment)

Dim commentCell As Range

For Each commentCell In commentRange

  If IsEmpty(commentCell.Offset(0, 2).Value) = True Then
    commentCell.Value = commentCell

      Else

    Dim firstConcatComment As Range
    Set firstConcatComment = commentCell.Offset(0, 2)

    commentCell.Value = commentCell & " | " & firstConcatComment

  End If

Next commentCell

Range("C1:E1").EntireColumn.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

End Sub
```

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: Excel 2016, latest VBA too.

Comment: Do you have access to TEXTJOIN()?  If so this could be done with a formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For something like this I prefer to load the entirety into an array then iterate through that array loading a second array.

It is quicker than iterating through ranges, as it only references the data on the sheet a couple of time instead of many.

```
Sub ColumnConcat()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet28") 'Change to your sheet name or ActiveSheet.


Dim rngArr() As Variant
Dim OArr() As Variant
rngArr = ws.UsedRange
ReDim OArr(LBound(rngArr, 1) To UBound(rngArr, 1), 1 To 2) As Variant

For i = LBound(rngArr, 1) To UBound(rngArr, 1)
    OArr(i, 1) = rngArr(i, 1) & " | "
    OArr(i, 2) = rngArr(i, 2)
    For j = 3 To UBound(rngArr, 2)
        If rngArr(i, j) = "" Then Exit For
        OArr(i, 1) = OArr(i, 1) & rngArr(i, j) & " | "
    Next j
    If OArr(i, 1) <> "" Then
        OArr(i, 1) = Left(OArr(i, 1), Len(OArr(i, 1)) - 3)
    End If
Next i

ws.UsedRange.Clear
ws.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(OArr, 1), UBound(OArr, 2)).Value = OArr
End Sub
```

Before:

[image]

After

[image]